# 3TB hard drive file access

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have two 3tb seagate hard drives in my machine for storage (second one is for backup), and I run windows 7.
During the weekend i put on a clean windows image on the c: drive (an ssd drive) and installed software, tweaked windows as i want it and (this is what i think might have caused my headache) updated drivers.

at one of the reboots during this whole process checkdisk decided to run due to inconsistency on the two 3TB drives. Back in windows, the drives were not recognized at all so i reverted back one step (making lots of images during the weekend) and stayed on the default driver, i believe it was the intel sata raid controller something driver...

Now i had access to the drives again, but a lot! of files were not accessible.
Video files either didnt play or were skipping and just appear broken. I figured checkdisk had broken them ,but after extensive deep scans with recovery software, nothing was found wrong, plus there was no "found.000" folders anywhere.

Finally, i booted the computer on an Ubuntu live usb stick, and just like that! i seem to have perfect access to said drives and files.

Question:
How can I get proper access to the drives and files in windows now, when i think the conclusion nothing is broken, just some access problem. (taking ownership of files and folders is not the answer, im the owner and on files that admin account is, adding me as owner doesnt help)

My computer is a Dell XPS i7 (not sure about model number, its a few years old)
Sorry for the long post, but i figured i should explain the situation properly.
Thanks in advance for any help, suggestion or ideas!

regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching between IDE and AHCI modes on the controllers that have the HDDs connected to them or you could install different drivers for those controllers.

Also, some motherboards have two such controllers, so you could plug the HDDs into a different one.

Comment: thank you, i have had progress by finding a driver that works but still some files seem corrupt, will look into AHCI modes!